# What does DT_TEXTREL mean and how to solve?

Tags: c++, x86-64, static-libraries, ld, linker-warning

I am working on a C++ project which uses a (legacy) static library (let's name it `foo.a`) which was compiled on an old Intel **32-bit** architecture (with *gcc-4*). I don't have the source code of this library so I can't rebuild it.

Now I have to make a porting of the entire project to an **x86-64** linux-based environment with *gcc-6.5*, and in a first phase I'm trying to compile all with `-m32` flag in order to not change anything.

The compilation phase goes well, but during the linking phase I get this warning:

> `ld: (foo.a)(x.o) relocation of read-only section '.ro-data'`
>
> `ld: warning: creating a DT_TEXTREL in object.`

In any case the executable is created, but in this moment I'm not able to test it (Yes I know, it seems a a disaster announced!).

I read something about the lack of `-fPIC` flag when `foo.a` was built and on the fact that on old *32-bit* architectures the `-fPIC` option was unnecessary.

My questions are:

1. What is `DT_TEXTREL`? I can't find any documentation on this term, only fragments on manuals.
2. How can I solve this problem without recompiling `foo.a`?
3. In case (question 2) is impossible to achieve, what problems should I expect on final executable by ignoring this warnings?

Thank you!

Comment: You're going to want `gcc -fno-pie -no-pie` so you can link code build without `-fPIE` into an executable.  32-bit x86 PIE has a large performance penalty, unlike x86-64, because it lacks PC-relative addressing, so you'd probably want to disable PIE code-gen for legacy 32-bit code even if your static library had been build to be PIE-compatible.  See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) for more about PIEs (focusing on 64-bit mode where having a 32-bit absolute address makes linking impossible instead of needing a runtime fixup)

Comment: AFAIK, a TEXTREL is a text relocation: a runtime fixup of an absolute address in a section that's normally read-only, like `.text` or `.rodata`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'll try this ASAP

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you, problem solved.